# Identificar e listar quais usuários visualizaram um post Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, laravel

Boa tarde, a fins de estudos, estou criando um sistema de comunicados, onde os usuários cadastram comunicados em uma linha do tempo, mas me deparei com a seguinte dúvida, Como eu faria para mostrar quais usuários visualizaram este comunicado? Comunicados são enviados para departamentos, ou usuários específicos ou para todos usuários.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se o usuário precisa estar logado para acessar o recurso. você pode simplesmente gravar o usuário acessando diretamente pelo Controller. Quando ele abrir a página vai gerar um Log do seu acesso.

Comment: No entanto, se você considerar que um recurso foi lido apenas após passado algum tempo. Cria um endpoint no seu projeto para registrar a leitura do recurso X pelo usuário Y. E controla pelo javascript, se o usuário ficar mais tempo que o determinado na página, vc salva pelo endpoint qual user leu qual recurso.